# jQuery animate forms on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have three sets of forms on the same page and only one form shown at a time. Forms can be navigated through each of the form's next step button. I would like to integrate a sliding animation/transition to the forms like the following.

I would like a solution using either CSS or jQuery. I tried an approach using CSS but it did not work.

Sample Animation
[image]

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w18szet5/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".form-set form:not(:first-child)").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
      $(this).hide();
  });

  $(".next").click(function() {
    if ($(".form-set form:visible").next().length != 0)
      $(".form-set form:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
      $(".form-set form:visible").hide();
      $(".form-set form:first").show();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-set">
        <form>
          <h4>
            Form Set 1
          </h4>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary next">Next Step</button>
        </form>

        <form style="display:none">
          <h4>
            Form Set 2
          </h4>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary next">Next Step</button>
        </form>

        <form style="display:none">
          <h4>
            Form Set 3
          </h4>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary next">Next Step</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try this [link](https://www.jquery-az.com/jquery/demo.php?ex=42.0_1)? It uses formAnimation.js

Comment: I would like to get this worked out without any plugins.

Comment: @GaniduRanasinghe I have answered that using plain `css`. please check the below snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do that using plain `css` using `animations` & `@keyframes` as per your requirement.
For the below example I have used `moveInRight` animation.

Your `css` should be in this way

```
.form-1,.form-2,.form-3{
    animation: moveInRight .5s ease-out;

}
@keyframes moveInRight {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(100px)
    }

    80% {
        transform: translateX(-10px)
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px)
    }
}
```

Here is the working snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".form-set form:not(:first-child)").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
      $(this).hide();
  });

  $(".next").click(function() {
    if ($(".form-set form:visible").next().length != 0)
      $(".form-set form:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
      $(".form-set form:visible").hide();
      $(".form-set form:first").show();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.form-1,.form-2,.form-3{
    animation: moveInRight .5s ease-out;
  

}
@keyframes moveInRight {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(100px)
    }

    80% {
        transform: translateX(-10px)
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px)
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-set">
        <form class="form-1">
          <h4>
            Form Set 1
          </h4>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary next">Next Step</button>
        </form>

        <form class="form-2" style="display:none">
          <h4>
            Form Set 2
          </h4>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary next">Next Step</button>
        </form>

        <form class="form-3" style="display:none">
          <h4>
            Form Set 3
          </h4>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary next">Next Step</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3uo4f0q/)

Comment: Glad to that I could help you. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

## You could also use CSS transforms and plain JavaScript.

```js
// Get the elements
const red = document.getElementById('red'),
  green = document.getElementById('green'),
  blue = document.getElementById('blue'),
  prev = document.getElementsByClassName('prev-button'),
  next = document.getElementsByClassName('next-button');

let visible = 1;

Array.from(next).forEach(button => {

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {

    if (visible === 1) {

      red.style.transform = 'translateX(-100%)';
      blue.style.transform = 'translateX(0)';

    } else if (visible === 2) {

      blue.style.transform = 'translateX(-100%)';
      green.style.transform = 'translateX(0)';

    }

    visible ++;

  });

});

Array.from(prev).forEach(button => {

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {

    if (visible === 3) {

      green.style.transform = 'translateX(100%)';
      blue.style.transform = 'translateX(0)';

    } else if (visible === 2) {

      blue.style.transform = 'translateX(100%)';
      red.style.transform = 'translateX(0)';

    }

    visible --;

  });

});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.elem {
  transition: all 1s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#blue, #green {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}


#red {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #f43b47 0%, #453a94 100%);
}

#blue {
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #a1c4fd 0%, #c2e9fb 100%);
}

#green {
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #84fab0 0%, #8fd3f4 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="elem" id="red">
    <button class="next-button">Next &rarr;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="elem" id="blue">
    <button class="prev-button">&larr; Back</button>
    <button class="next-button">Next &rarr;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="elem" id="green">
    <button class="prev-button">&larr; Back</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Changing the value of `translate`, you could make the elements animate from and to different directions.